# The geometric interpretation of the gradient for a function written in quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, quadratic-forms

Alright, this question is going to be **really** broad, and that's my fault because I am extremely lost. I appreciate all the help!

As far as I understand, writing a quadratic multivariable function in quadratic form means writing it like this:

$$f(\vec{x})=\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}+\vec{x}^T\vec{b} + c$$

Where $A$ is a symmetric matrix holding the quadratic coefficients and the halves of the cross-coefficients, $b$ is a vector holding the linear coefficients, and $c$ is some constant.

*(I may be wrong about the above...)*

My friend was trying to explain to me a geometric reason why the gradient of $f(\vec{x})=\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}$, with none of the other terms, is $2A\vec{x}$.

I honestly wasn't understanding what he was saying, but he kept on mentioning **spheres** and **ellipsoids** and talking about growing $\vec{x}$ in the direction that "grows the ellipsoid the fastest"...or something like that.

Can anyone explain what he was talking about, as geometrically as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure he did not say $2 A \vec{x}$?

Comment: @MarkFischler Yep lol, fixing that now! Thanks! I get that the gradient is $2A\vec{x}$, I just want to understand the geometry of what he was talking about.

Comment: That scale factor is irrelevant to your friend’s geometrical hand-waving. $2A\vec x$ and $A\vec x$ point in the same direction.

Comment: @amd yep, I know. Could u help me understand what he was saying? Or is this handwaving TOO handwavy?

Comment: To focus answers to your question: are you asking specifically why the gradient of the quadric $x^TAx$ is $2Ax$, or are you also interested in properties of gradients in general, e.g., they point in the direction of greatest increase, they’re normal to level surfaces, &c.?